# Making [alphabetic] tag a synonym of [alphabetical]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I think [alphabetic](/questions/tagged/alphabetic) should be made a synonym for [alphabetical](/questions/tagged/alphabetical). Probably not worth a merge since people will keep writing one or the other, as they are synonyms in English as well.

Comment: My inner Grammar Nazi keeps insisting that "alphabetic" is less-proper than "alphabetical" in all cases.  So, I'm on the fence about this one, although [this](http://grammarist.com/usage/alphabetic-alphabetical/) helps.

Comment: @Jamal Ok. Fair point. I'm not a native English language speaker, so I wasn't aware of all those nuances between the two. They are indeed not perfect synonyms. Still it seems to me that on SO they are used to tag the same category of questions, so letting them be synonyms makes sense maybe.